# Release memory on switching TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I've many TabItem in a window with Frame and load UserControls inside Frame when TabItem gets clicked as you can see in below pic:
[image]

**Problem:**

1. When first TabItem clicked and "Sale UserControl" gets load it takes memory **121Mb**.
2. On switching 2nd TabItem it takes **128Mb**
3. then again switch back to first TabItem it takes **142Mb** memory. Same scenario will be for the other TabItems, each switch takes memory and not get freed of last one TabItem.
4. I switched two TabItem 10 times, memory consumption seems upto **308MB** which is alarming.

This incremented memory i think directed to Memory Leaks. but i can't understand from where. please help,

Diagnostic Tool result:

[image]

Code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Inventory_Control"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Inventory_Control.UserControls"
        x:Class="Inventory_Control.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="Images/app_icon.png">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="160"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="90"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,5,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,3,0,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.079*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TabControl x:Name="TabControl" Padding="0" MouseUp="TabControl_MouseUp">

                <TabItem MouseUp="TabItem_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#3e7038">
                            <Image Source="Images/sale.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Sale" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>

                <TabItem x:Name="ItemsTab" MouseUp="ItemsTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Background="#0073c4">
                            <Image Source="Images/product.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Items"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="CategoryTab" MouseUp="CategoryTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#404040">
                            <Image Source="Images/category.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Category"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="TypeTab" MouseUp="TypeTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#404040">
                            <Image Source="Images/type.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Type"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="LocationTab" MouseUp="LocationTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#404040">
                            <Image Source="Images/location.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Location"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="CustomerTab" MouseUp="CustomerTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#FF364834">
                            <Image Source="Images/customer.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Customer"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="SupplierTab" MouseUp="SupplierTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#FF364834">
                            <Image Source="Images/supplier.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Supplier"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Name="LedgerTab">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#FF7F7C7C">
                            <Image Source="Images/ledger.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Ledger"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>


                <TabItem x:Name="UserTab" MouseUp="UserTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#FFB17369">
                            <Image Source="Images/user.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="User" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="ExpenseTab" MouseUp="AddExpenses_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#cc6d00">
                            <Image Source="Images/expense.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Expense" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Name="ReportTab" MouseUp="TabItem_MouseUp_2">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#00879c">
                            <Image Source="Images/report.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Report"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>

                <TabItem x:Name="HistoryTab" MouseUp="HistoryTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="#FF324F54">
                            <Image Source="Images/history.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="History"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>

                <TabItem x:Name="InventoryTrailTab" MouseUp="InventoryTrailTab_MouseUp">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel  Background="Tomato">
                            <Image Source="Images/history.png" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Inventory Trail"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>

            </TabControl>

        </Viewbox> 

        <!--<Button Name="LogoutBtn" Height="auto" MinWidth="50" Width="50" Content="Logout" Grid.Column="1"/>-->

        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="mainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

cs:

```
using Inventory_Control.Classes;

namespace Inventory_Control
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int selectedTab = 0;

        string userType = Util.GetUserType();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainFrame.Content = new FileTab();


            if (userType.Equals(Util.editor))
            {
                EditorPrivilidges();
            }

            if (userType.Equals(Util.salesman))
            {
                SalesmanPrevilidges();
            }
        }

        void SalesmanPrevilidges()
        {
            EditorPrivilidges();
            ItemsTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            CategoryTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            TypeTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            LocationTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            CustomerTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            SupplierTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }

        void EditorPrivilidges()
        {
            ReportTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            HistoryTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            UserTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ExpenseTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            LedgerTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void TabItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 0)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new FileTab();
            }
        }

        private void SaleTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ItemsTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 1)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new ItemsTab();
            }
        }

        private void TabItem_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CategoryTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 2)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = null;
                mainFrame.Content = new CategoryTab();
            }
        }

        private void TypeTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 3)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new TypeTab();
            }
        }

        private void LocationTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 4)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new LocationTab();
            }
        }

        private void CustomerTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 5)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new CustomerTab();
            }
        }

        private void SupplierTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 6)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new SupplierTab();
            }
        }

        private void UserTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 8)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new UserTab();
            }
        }

        private void TabItem_MouseUp_2(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 10)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new ReportTab();
            }
        }

        private void HistoryTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 11)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new HistoryTab();
            }
        }

        private void InventoryTrailTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedTab != 12)
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new InventoryTrail();
            }
        }

        private void SalesmanTab_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mainFrame.Content != new SalesmanTab())
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new SalesmanTab();
            }
        }



        private void AddExpenses_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mainFrame.Content != new AddExpenses())
            {
                mainFrame.Content = new AddExpenses();
            }
        }

        private void TabControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            selectedTab = TabControl.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you hooking up events anywhere (then not unhooking them) ? if so if in when the form/tab closes make sure to unsubscribe or else you get this memory-leak problem.  of course i'm just guessing as i can't see all the code

Comment: please read cs file

Comment: yip thought so.  did not scroll far enough f=down so apologies. i count 16 events.  change the way you subscribe to these events using the `+=` way so you can then also unsubscribe easily `-=`

Comment: And how did you work out you have a memory leak, where did you get these values from?

Comment: i've seen memory usage from default visual studio tool called "Diagnostic Tool"

Comment: @JohnB please give an example how to use + and -

Comment: @TheGeneral please see my edited question

Comment: I'm not satisfied yet that this is a memory leak, or a least not as bad as what you think, you need to use a memory profiler, with those results it will pinpoint if there is a leak, and what it is.

Comment: Button.Click += myButtonClickHandler; //subscribe

Comment: Button.Click -= myButtonClickHandler; //unsubscribe

Comment: @TheGeneral then why memory gets increases on every switch?

Comment: @JohnB are you sure with your method memory gets free?

Comment: @zohaib just because your memory goes up does not mean your application is leaking memory, this is just the way operating systems and .net work. it doesn't aggressively give you back memory when it creates objects as that would be time consuming, you need to do a lot of reading to understand why.. start here [Memory Management and Garbage Collection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/memory-management-and-gc) . Also if you want to workout if you have written leaky code, you need to use a memory profiler (correctly)

Comment: no as @TheGeneral says - nothing can be be determined conclusively unless you have `proof` of a leak.  this unsubscribing method i have commented on is good practice.  do some research yourself.